# Vectors and Scalars

Tags: kinematics, vectors

How is Momentum $mv$ integrate form a Vector product to produce a Scalar [ Kinetic Energy $(1/2)mv^2$]?
Is this mathematical proof of the vector to scalar change in Absolute Calculus, Number Theory, Topology, Quaternion's, Octonions or sum other discipline of mathematics?

Comment: More simple than that: it's [*linear algebra*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_algebra) (specifically the dot product: $KE=p^2/2m=\left(\mathbf p\cdot\mathbf p\right)/2m$).

Comment: It is completely unclear to me what you're asking, and what a scalar product of vectors should have to do with number theory, topology or octonions.

Answer (score 3):

You have the momentum given by the vector:

$\vec{p}=m\vec{v}$

$\vec{v}=$  being the velocity vector.

Now if you integrate the momentum with respect to velocity then you have the integral:

$\int\vec{p} \cdot d\vec{v}=m\int \vec{v} \cdot d\vec{v}$

Where $\vec{v} \cdot d\vec{v}$ is the dot(scalar) product between the two vectors $\vec{v}$ and $d\vec{v}$ which is a scalar that is given by

$|\vec{v}| |d\vec{v}|cos\theta=vdv$

Therefore

$m\int \vec{v} \cdot d\vec{v}=m\int vdv=\dfrac{1}{2}mv^2 $.

So your confusion lies in the fact that we were able to extract a scalar quantity out of a vector one. this makes sense once you realize the integral of the **dot product between two vectors which gives a scalar, is itself a scalar.**

Comment: I am gratefully for your excellent reply.
  
I am aware of these definitions and my question is philosophical in nature. I am asking if the Trigonometric functions are a factor? 

Is the vector part just plane dropped or is it because the transcendental functions (cosine and sine ) are normal to each other ? The derivatives and integrals are: also; normal to each other. Would this be the reason for the scalar?

Comment: @s.c.crowl I cannot make out what you're saying, can you elaborate may be?

Comment: Vectors are defined in Group Theory along with Scalars. The question might best be ask: How does one get from one group to the other group by integration or a differential operation? My apologies for awkward questions.

Comment: @s.c.crowl One obtains a scalar by applying the dot product on two vectors. Conversely, By taking the gradient of a scalar, one gets a vector.

Comment: OMar Ngid: your last comment was helpful.